# Make 2 sets of checkboxes required if a checkbox is not selected

Tags: laravel, checkbox

I've a checkbox called "no_industry".

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="no_industry" id="no_industry" value="NoIndustry">No Industry Focus</label>
```

If this value is no selected user must select a value from any of the following check boxes list.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="indus_communication" name="industry[]" value="Communications/CSI">Communications / CSI</label>
```

```
<input type="checkbox" id="indus_communication" name="solution[]" value="Communications/CSI">Communications / CSI</label>
```

How do I do that?

I've added the following validation, but seems it is not working.

```
    'industry' => ['required_if:no_industry,NULL'],
    'solution' => ['required_if:no_industry,NULL']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its taking null as a value

Here is an alternative solution for it you can try as

```
$this->validate($request, [

        'industry' => 'required_without:no_industry',
        'solution' => 'required_without:no_industry',
     ]);
```

or as

```
  'industry' => ['required_without:no_industry'],
  'solution' => ['required_without:no_industry']
```

Try This Hope it will Help--!!

Comment: I want only user to select one from either solution or industry. This validation is prompting to select both.